# Ubuntu 20.04 or 22.04, how can I add additional panels?

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, panel

My old computer is loaded with 18.04.5 LTS and the panels on the side, top, & bottom of the screen are dynamic and I can drag and drop most any icon/program to the panels and I have an instant shortcut.  I can lock and unlock these icons and move them around in order and also move them from left panel, to bottom, top, etc.  I can also right click the panel and I'm offered "+ Add to panel"

I just bought a new computer and loaded Ubuntu 20.04.4 (& 22.04 in another try) and it seems that only the left panel is working and I can't arrange the program icons.  It seems that I can only "add to favorites" and all the icons stack on the left side in what seems to be alphabetical order.

I even downgraded the new install to 18 but it has all of the 20.04/22.04 characteristics for panels and did not revert to the same as my old version 18.04.

Using Ubuntu 20.04 or 22.04 is there a program or hack that will allow me to restore the functionality of the panels that I had on 18.04?

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Thanks @guiverc, I've updated the post to reflect this.

Comment: If you want to go for Xubuntu, I highly recommend installing it from scratch, rather than installing `xubuntu-desktop` on the existing system, especially if the system is freshly installed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @HolyBlackCat, can you say why that recommendation?  Is there some interference?  thanks

Comment: Last time I tried this, I believe I've got some redundant software: like two image viewers, one from Ubuntu and one from Xubuntu. Cleaning this up manually was too tedious.

Comment: thanks @HolyBlackCat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default Ubuntu desktop is based on Gnome Shell, and does not support adding multiple panels (unless one codes this using Gnome Shell extensions). Instead, change to a different desktop environment that is better fitting your desired workflow. Some options include Ubuntu Mate with the Mate desktop, Xubuntu with the Xfce desktop, Kubuntu with the Plasma desktop...

Instead of proceeding to a fresh installation with a different Ubuntu flavor, you also can install a different desktop environment on an existing installation. For example, `sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop` will install all default packages of Xubuntu.

After installing a desktop environment, you can log into it. Log out first, select your user, and before entering your password, click the cog wheel on the bottom right to select one of the installed desktop environments.

Comment: Thanks @vanadium, just the info I was looking for!